# display ACF repater field in archive page

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, terms

I created ACF repeater field for custom taxonomy terms. Repeater consist of two field "Question" and "Answer" . By this way I want to create FAQ section for each taxonomy term.
Thought I can show other custom fields easily in archive field, But I could not succeded with repeater field . Please help me.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$meta = get_field('test', $term);
but when want to output the acf repeater have no success.

$term = get_queried_object();
if (have_rows('faq', $term)) :
    while (have_rows('faq', $term)) : the_row();
        echo get_sub_field('question');
        echo get_sub_field('answer');
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) and [`have_rows()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) work with post/term ID, not the whole "**queried object**". You should try `$term = get_queried_object()->term_id;` in line 1. Also it is unnecessery to set `$term` again at line 3.

Comment: thank you very much it works now